# How to count and then compute the total average in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

Each line in my dataset is a sale and my goal is to compute the average time a client buys during his lifetime.

I have already grouped and counted by clientId like this:

```
byClientId = GROUP sales BY clientId;
countByClientId = FOREACH byClientId GENERATE group, count($1);
```

This creates a table with 2 columns: clientId, count of transactions.

Now, I am trying to get the total average of the second column (i.e. the overall average of sales to same client). I am using this code:

```
groupCount = GROUP countByClientId all;
avg = foreach groupCount generate AVG($1);
```

But I get this error message:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 18, column 31> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG 
as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

How to get the overall average of the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been simpler for us with a sample of input data.. I created my own, to be sure that my solution would work. You only have one mistake : once you grouped all your schema become `group:chararray,countByClientId:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,:long)}`

So, $1 refers to a bag and this is why you can't compute the mean. If you want to access $1 (which is the second element) inside this bag you have two choices, either `$1.$1`, or `countByClientId.$1`. So your last line should be :

```
avg = foreach groupCount generate AVG(countByClientId.$1);
```

I hope it's clear.